# Unix/Linux program that can handle all popular compression/archiving formats (e.g.tar, gzip, bzip2, zip)?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, compression, archiving

I sometimes get confused by the varying command line options I need to run common Unix archiving and compression software (e.g. gzip, bzip2, zip, tar).

Is there a program out there that can just Do What I Mean for common cases? For example:

```
program --compress --gzip foobar
program --extract foobar.tar.bz2
program --extract foo.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`atool`](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/) is designed for this job. A copy of the man page is available [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/atool).

To compress files use

```
apack ARCHIVE FILE
```

and to decompress them use

```
aunpack ARCHIVE
```

(alternatively you can use `atool -a` and `atool -x` respectively).

It works with pretty much any archive format you can think of including gzip, bzip, lzip, 7z, rar, ar, deb, rpm, jar[1] and most combinations of tar and a compression method.

The advantage of this over 7zip is that *7zip removes executable permissions*. So, for example, 7zip makes it much more difficult to install software from archived sources because you need to manually `chmod +x` the appropriate files before running any make or any install scripts.

---

[1] The online man page linked is for an older version that doesn't handle jar files.

Answer (score 8):

As example **7z**.

```
7z a -tgzip foobar.gz foobar
7z e foobar.gz
```

Where `a` - add files to archive, `-t{Type}` - Set type of archive (7z,  zip,  gzip,  bzip2 or tar), `e` - extract files from archive.
More information `man 7z`.

Comment: You shouldn't need the -t option most of the time -- 7-zip will guess archive type from common file extensions if possible.

Comment: There's a major problem with 7zip: it will remove file permissions even when extracting archives that should preserve this information! This greatly complicates the installation of software from archives. Use `atool` instead (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

[`tar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar), when configured correctly, can do this all (except the unzip maybe) easily.

```
tar --create --gzip --file out.tar.gz in in2 in3
# same thing
tar -czf out.tar.gz in in2 in3

tar --extract --file in.tar
tar -xf in.tar
```

This will work for gzipped and bzip2ed files as well. (Assuming you actually have such programs installed.)

Edit: Oh yeah, forgot about the unzip. That's not included in `tar` presumably because of patent reasons or such. Simply use the [`unzip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) application to extract those:

```
unzip in.zip
```